# Realm loadJsonFromString fails to put string

Tags: android, database, realm

I have downloaded example from git for testing. I came across jsonExample where you can loadJson from String.

```
private void loadJsonFromString() {
    String json = "{ city: \"Aarhus\", votes: 99 }";
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.createObjectFromJson(City.class, json);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

But when you check in .realm city: Aarhus was never stored in database. Why??

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the problem. That because the key 'city' doesn't match Object's property 'name'.

```
//Change 
String json = "{ city: \"Aarhus\", votes: 99 }";

//to
String json = "{ name: \"Aarhus\", votes: 99 }";
```

@realmDeveloper
I know that it is just a minor issue, but please fix it for avoiding any confusion.

Comment: Thanks for finding that. We will fix that asap